# Is there a way to invert vertical and horizontal scrolling Fullpage JS

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

This was originally proposed here on github issues section:

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/200

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.fullpage({
      onSlideLeave: function (anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) {
        //For the section 1, slide 0 to the right...
        if (index == 1 && slideIndex == 0 && direction == 'right') {
            var section2 = $('#section1');
            var section3 = $('#section2');
            $.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(0);
            $.fn.fullpage.scrollSlider(section2, 1);
            $.fn.fullpage.scrollSlider(section3, 1);
            $.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(1000);
        }
      }
    });
});
```

But this post is from 2014 and the `scrollSlider` function is no longer available. I am new to jQuery. Please explain how i can achieve this. I have been trying to get an answer from the dev but i do not seem to understand as there is no explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your html mark up have you set the id for the sections as id="section2" and id="section3" etc?

Comment: No the ID’s are ‘section1’ and ‘section2’. Dont mind the variables ‘var section2’ and ‘var section3’. The ‘scrollSlider()’ is no longer available in fullpage js. I have a two static sections setup for testing. The ID is ‘section1’ and ‘section2’

Answer (score 0):

Not something that fullPage.js provides.
You'll have to code it by yourself.

Comment: That is the reason why i am here... to seek help.

Comment: Just saying it because the solution implies writing and changing quite a lot of code. Basically, re-writing a huge part of the library. You won't probably get any answer here, unless donde using the Interlocked Slides extension together with Scroll Horizontally and fullpage.s callbacks and methods.

Comment: Ok so assuming I changed the key bindings to move section when i press left and right arrow keys, how can i change the animation direction? Any ideas?

Comment: As I said, not easy. Need a whole rewrite.

Comment: Why was this possibility not implemented before? I have seen a lot of posts requesting this. It is common sense to move section left/right and slides up/down. Why was this inverted in the first place?

Comment: Because I can't do everything? :D 
I'm human and I have a limited amount of time.

Comment: It’s common sense to move section left/right. And slides up/down. I am not saying it’s bad. I love fullpage and everything about it :) but i have been stuck with my project for over 2 weeks because I couldn’t resolve this and I don’t have that kind of money to spend on a simple (from my understanding) solution. Fullpage is the best well, fullpage jquery lib i have seen yet. And a great thanks to you.

Comment: Sorry about that! Hope you find a way to solve your issue!